# outside javascript not work with onsen framewowrk

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui

i am use onsen.ui framework but when i include any script he do not working 
how i do accept include javascript in the framework

```js
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
```

```css
span{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <title>CodePen - Navigator</title>
    
    
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/css/onsenui.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/css/onsen-css-components.css'>

    
    <script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>

    
    
  </head>

  <body translate="no" >

    <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Simple Navigation</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <br>
         <button onclick="scrollWin()">Click me to scroll horizontally no work!</button><br><br>
                  <script>
function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 140);
}
</script>
      <span><br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test</span>
    </div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>



    <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/js/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/js/onsenui.min.js'></script>

        <script>
      ons.bootstrap();
      //# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>

    
    <script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>

    
  </body></html>
```

Comment: I recommend starting with the tutorials:  http://tutorial.onsen.io/?framework=vanilla&category=Reference&module=page as you are mixing code with your markup in ways that it should not be done which is why it is not compiled.

Comment: I did not understand please explain more @Munsterlander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is not that the javascript is not working but rather you're just trying to scroll the wrong element.

Onsen UI's `ons-page` elements create their own content element (`div.page__content`) and that is used for scrolling purposes. So you can just scroll that element. However it does not have a method scrollTo, rather you can just set the `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` properties like this:

```
document.querySelector('.page__content').scrollTop = 140; // for vertical
document.querySelector('.page__content').scrollLeft = 140; // for horizontal
```

If you use this for your `scrollWin` function you will be fine.

Also note - if you want to use horizontal scrolling you should have some content which is wider, so that you can actually scroll the element.

For the purpose of the snippet I inserted the following:

```
<div style="position:absolute;width: 200%;height: 10px;"></div>
```

I think you get the gist of it.

And finally if you want to execute something when onsen is ready - for example if you want to call your autoscroll function you can do:

```
ons.ready(function(){ ... });
```

Here is your modified snippet:

```js
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
```

```css
span{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <title>CodePen - Navigator</title>
    
    
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/css/onsenui.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/css/onsen-css-components.css'>

    
    <script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>

    
    
  </head>

  <body translate="no" >

    <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Simple Navigation</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <br>
         <button onclick="scrollWin()">Click me to scroll horizontally no work!</button><br><br>
                  <script>
function scrollWin() {
    document.querySelector('.page__content').scrollTop = 140; // for vertical
    document.querySelector('.page__content').scrollLeft = 140; // for horizontal
}
</script>
      <div style="position:absolute;width: 200%;height: 10px;"></div>
      <span><br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test</span>
    </div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>



    <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/js/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/js/onsenui.min.js'></script>

        <script>
      ons.bootstrap();
      //# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>

   
    
  </body></html>
```

Comment: i want javascript work in <ons-template> but he only work in <ons-navigator> ... pleas give me solution @llia yatchev

Comment: rather than putting the script in the `ons-template` you can give the `ons-page` tag an id like `<ons-page id="myPage">` and then do `document.addEventListener(function(e){ if (e.target.id == "myPage") ... })` where `...` is your code for that specific page :)

Comment: i will understand with jsfiddl pleas @llia Yatchev

Comment: Oops - I missed the event name - for v1 it's pageinit, v2 - init. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2kaLpgb/) - but you should also try to understand things even without fiddles :P - if you're not sure how to use `document.addEventListener` i think both w3schools and the mozilla docs are good places to start :)

Comment: Also since most of these questions are turning into discussions I would suggest moving them to the [onsen community website](https://community.onsen.io)

Comment: Yes, I'm member  in onsen community..  the example now works .. if I've ever had another question, how can I ask you a master @llia Yatchev

Comment: Well if you expect the question to have a single answer you can still ask here. If you think it may be turn into a discussion you can ask in the community directly. I may not be as active there as some of the other members, however there are plenty of others such as munsterlander and fran diox who can answer you in a more timely manner.

Comment: Now I do not have a question but I mean in the future if I have a difficult question in the (onsen ui) How do I communicate to you  master 
and if you can give me channel in youtube or site or book to learn onsen from beginner to pro master @ Ilia Yatchev

Comment: Maybe for simple questions - ask here at SO, for difficult ones - at the community. For youtube channel I don't think there is one yet - I think there is only 1 video which you can find in the [getting started page](https://onsen.io/getting-started/). In my opinion the best place to learn onsen right now is probably the [interactive tutorial](//tutorial.onsen.io) - it may not get you to pro, but definitely to intermediate level. After that you can just simply try out some things and ask in the community. Also when you run into a problem you can try to debug it with the browser inspector. :)