# javascript no working with onsen.ui

Tags: javascript, html, css, onsen-ui

javascript do not working with onsen.ui framework 
for example i use javascript to show position px body whene scroll down but no working and any javascript... when i remove link (link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/css/onsenui.css')
he working but Some features not working ... Anyone help me I'm tired of this

```html
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <title>CodePen - Navigator</title>
    
    
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/css/onsenui.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/css/onsen-css-components.css'>
    <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/js/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/js/onsenui.min.js'></script>
    
    <script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>

      <script>
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  
    var top = this.scrollY,
        left = this.scrollX;
  
    var horizontalScroll = document.querySelector(".horizontalScroll"),
        verticalScroll = document.querySelector(".verticalScroll");
    
    horizontalScroll.innerHTML = "Scroll X: " + left + "px";
      verticalScroll.innerHTML = "Scroll Y: " + top + "px";
        document.getElementById("input1").value=verticalScroll.innerHTML =top;
  
}, false);
        
      </script>
        

    
  </head>

  <body translate="no" >

    <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Simple Navigation</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
<br><br>
<div class="wrapper" style="position:fixed;">
    <div class="horizontalScroll">Scroll (x,y) to </div>
    <div class="verticalScroll">see me in action</div>
    
</div>
      <p>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br></p>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>

        <script>
      ons.bootstrap();

    </script>
    <script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
      
  }
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is almost a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638415/outside-javascript-not-work-with-onsen-framewowrk?answertab=oldest#tab-top), so you may be interested in looking at my answer there.

The short version is:

- you need to use an element `.page__content` instead of window
- you can access its `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` properties
- to scroll horizontally you need some wider child element
- use `ons.ready` for initialization code

In the referenced link you can find a more detailed explanation.

Modified snippet:

```html
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <title>CodePen - Navigator</title>
    
    
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/css/onsenui.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/css/onsen-css-components.css'>
    <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/js/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/js/onsenui.min.js'></script>
    
    <script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>

      <script>
        
ons.ready(function(){
  var content = document.querySelector('.page__content');
  var horizontalScroll = document.querySelector(".horizontalScroll");
  var verticalScroll = document.querySelector(".verticalScroll");

  content.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
horizontalScroll.innerHTML = "Scroll X: " + content.scrollLeft + "px";
verticalScroll.innerHTML = "Scroll Y: " + content.scrollTop + "px";
  });
});
      </script>
        

    
  </head>

  <body translate="no" >

    <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Simple Navigation</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
<br><br>
<div class="wrapper" style="position:fixed;">
    <div class="horizontalScroll">Scroll (x,y) to </div>
    <div class="verticalScroll">see me in action</div>
    
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;width: 200%;height: 10px;"></div>          

<p>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br></p>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>

        <script>
      ons.bootstrap();

    </script>
    <script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
      
  }
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you (llia) has helped me, a question in the other also is from my friend .. now I want you to give me the base if used (javascript) external to the (onsen ui) Why do I change the

Comment: @mody I think your comment was cut off accidentally. You can see the code in the snippet - the `ons.ready` call is where the "magic" happens. As for why you need to use (change to) the `.page__content` element - it's because that is where the scroll event happens when using Onsen UI. And the scroll event is an exceptional one which doesn't propagate to window, so you cannot catch it from there. Since the comment was cut off I am not sure what you meant exactly. I think I will be afk for about 22 hours, so I can respond tomorrow again if I failed to answer properly.

Comment: I do not know how to thank you for the great help thanxs llia... I mean, if I add another a section (javascript) what the rules should be changed .. For example:1-(window must convert to page__content)
2-use ons-ready()
3-?
Are there any other rules??

Comment: now [the example](https://jsfiddle.net/memohmtl/jkuLswmw/)  do not working .. how i do ??

Comment: @mody it seems you pretty much got it - the only thing which you missed is that in your example you have multiple pages, so you can give the main page an id and listen for scrolls on that page - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pp3qzkq/) - for example `<ons-page id="mainPage">` and then `#mainPage .page__content`. If you want a horizontal scroll don't forget to have something wider. Also if you have further probems you can also discuss them at https://community.onsen.io

Comment: I was waiting for you since yesterday .. I tried your example he work but when i go to page2 and go back to page1 the script no working pleas solve the problem sir @Ilia Yatchev

Comment: ok - in that case it seems you are creating a new page 1 when you go back and that is why the script stops working. replace `ons.ready(function(){ ... })` with `document.addEventListener('init', function(e) { if (e.target.id == 'mainPage') ... })` - that way the code will run each time when you initialize page1.

Comment: i tried it but not working please edit your fiddle and give me ready@ Ilia Yatchev

Comment: oh - my bad - I'm used to version 2 - in version 1 the event is called 'pageinit' instead of 'init'